# Reload or Refresh Page when clicking

Tags: javascript

Hi any help how can i refresh may page everytime i click a link? heres my code

```
function myFunction(id) { 
      var x=document.getElementById(id) 
      document.getElementById('t_id').value=x.id; 
}
```

HTML

```
<a href="docview.php?id=30" id="30" onclick="myFunction(30)" class="30" 
          target="iframe_a">August 7, 2013</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will refresh each time if not then use this code:

```
function myFunction(id) { 
      var x=document.getElementById(id) 
      document.getElementById('t_id').value=x.id; 
      return true;
}
```

And HTML will be:

```
<a href="docview.php?id=30" id="30" onclick="return myFunction(30)" class="30" 
          target="iframe_a">August 7, 2013</a></li>
```

OR you can add this line in the JS function at the end:

```
window.location.reload();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the reload function :

```
<script>
function myFunction(somval)
  {
  location.reload();
  }
</script>
```